# Index Out of Bound exception while rendering RDLC Reports in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

My ASP.NET Core MVC project has several reports. To render the reports as PDF, I'm using `AspNetCore.Reporting` library.

This library works fine for a single report but due to some cache issues it throws an exception while generating another report. The solution I found on the internet was to run report generation as a new process but I don't know how to implement that.

I found the suggestion to use Tmds.ExecFunction to run report generation as a seperate process. But I dont know how to pass parameters to the function.

Here is my code:

````
  string ReportName = "invoiceDine";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = GetInvoiceItems(invoiceFromDb.Id);
            Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            param.Add("bParam", $"{invoiceFromDb.Id}");
            param.Add("gParam", $"{salesOrderFromDb.Guests}");
            param.Add("tParam", $"{invoiceFromDb.Table.Table}");
            param.Add("dParam", $"{invoiceFromDb.Time}");
            param.Add("totalP", $"{invoiceFromDb.SubTotal}");
            param.Add("t1", $"{tax1}");
            param.Add("t2", $"{tax2}");
            param.Add("tA1", $"{tax1Amount}");
            param.Add("tA2", $"{tax2Amount}");
            param.Add("AT1", $"{totalAmountWithTax1}");
            param.Add("AT2", $"{totalAmountWithTax2}");
            param.Add("terminalParam", $"{terminalFromDb.Name}");
            param.Add("addressParam", $"{t.Address}");
            param.Add("serviceParam", "Service Charges of applicable on table of " + $"{personForServiceCharges}" + " & Above");
            var result = reportService.GenerateReport(ReportName, param, "dsInvoiceDine", dt);
            return File(result,"application/Pdf");


This is my version of the function:                                     
``` public byte[] GenerateReport(string ReportName, Dictionary<string,string> Parameters,string DataSetName,DataTable DataSource )
        {
            string guID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
            string fileDirPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Replace("POS_Website.dll", string.Empty);

            string ReportfullPath = Path.Join(fileDirPath, "\\Reports");
            string JsonfullPath = Path.Join(fileDirPath,"\\JsonFiles");

            string rdlcFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.rdlc", ReportfullPath, ReportName);
            string generatedFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.pdf", JsonfullPath, guID);
            string jsonDataFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.json", JsonfullPath, guID);
            File.WriteAllText(jsonDataFilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataSource));

            FunctionExecutor.Run((string[] args) =>
            {
            // 0 : Data file path - jsonDataFilePath 
            // 1 : Filename - generatedFilePath 
            // 2 : RDLCPath - rdlcFilePath 
            ReportResult result;
           
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
            LocalReport report = new LocalReport(args[2]);
            DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(File.ReadAllText(args[0]));
            report.AddDataSource(args[3], dt);
            result = report.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, 1,Parameters);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(result.MainStream);
                }
            }, new string[] {jsonDataFilePath, generatedFilePath, rdlcFilePath, DataSetName });

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine("", generatedFilePath), FileMode.Open))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memory);
            }

            File.Delete(generatedFilePath);
            File.Delete(jsonDataFilePath);
            memory.Position = 0;
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
                                                                        
But it throws exception "Field marshaling is not supported by ExecFunction" on line: 
 var result = reportService.GenerateReport(ReportName, param, "dsInvoiceDine", dt);
````

Comment: Here is a suggestion but how to pass parameters to the function [https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/9#issuecomment-990626517]

Comment: Which line is causing the error?  Can you include all the code including the method calling this method?  Also, put edits into the question.  Comments mat be non-permanent.

Comment: @mcalex Can you help me with how to move my report genration logic to console App and then run that console App from my Asp.Net core mvc app as new Process.

Comment: I'm Stuck with the error for last two weeks. I shall be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Are those template strings in your actual code?  Stuff like:  "YOUR DLL NAME", "YOUR RDLC NAME" and "YOUR SERVICE METHOD TO FETCH DATA" etc?

Comment: Yes I have Updated my code.. It throws an exception "Field marshaling is not supported by ExecFunction".

Comment: OK, have you had a look at [ReportViewerCore.NETCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerCore.NETCore/).  But this is a whole 'nother problem that requires a new/reworded question.

Comment: ReportViewerCore.NetCore is supported by .Net Core 3.1, my project is in .Net 5

Comment: Are you sure? "This project is aimed at porting Microsoft Reporting Services (Report Viewer) to [.NET Core 3.1 **+**.](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/)" and [Added .NET 5 support](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1515), but your new question is probably going to get a better solution.

Comment: I have tried it in .Net 5 it does not work. it has a dependency of .Net 3.1 core.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to run report generation as a seperate process. Just Dont Pass extension as 1
in:

```
 var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, 1, param);
```

The Solution is:

```
  int ext = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks >> 10);
  var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, ext, param);
```